# have I categorized theses definitions of compactness correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I am studying compactness, and I need to be confirmed if I have categorized the definition of compactness correctly. I would appreciate if you take a look and see if I am correct in recognizing the definitions?

is this the DEFENITION of compact metric space $M$? $M$ is said to be compact, if $M$ is complete and totally bounded.
is this the DEFENITION of compact subset $A$ in a metric space $M$? $A$ is said to be compact, if every open cover of $A$ has a finite subcover.
is this the DEFENITION of compact subset $A$ in Real numbers? $A$ is said to be compact, if every sequence from $A$ has a subsequence converging to a point $a\in A$ .
are these correct?

Comment: The open cover definition is the most general and the other two are special cases.

Comment: Cf. [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem):  a subset $\mathbb R^n$ is closed and bounded iff every open cover has a finite subcover; and [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem):  any bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ has a convergent subsequence

Comment: so if I am going to prove a metric space is compact by definition, I am not supposed to prove it is complete and ttly bounded. But I am supposed to show every open cover of M!!!( what would be an open cover of M!?) has a finite subcover?

Comment: An open cover of $A$ is a collection of open sets whose union contains $A$